# Streaming movies from Windows Home Server 2011 to iPad

Tags: ipad, video-streaming, silverlight, windows-home-server

Is there a way to Stream movies from my Remote website to the iPad? I gave it a try and was able to log in and view all my files however, when trying to stream i get an error saying Silverlight is not supported. Is there a known workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue has been confirmed silverlight is not supported as a stand alone on the Ipad. found a work around using Remote Potato.